# Have Makefile create rpm spec file

Tags: rpm, make, rpmbuild

I have a `makefile` to build my program then a `makefile` to build my `rpm` package in addition to an `rpm spec` file to create the `rpm`. Right now the spec file is manually maintained. However for future flexibility I am curious is there any way other then having the `makefile` `echo` into a `spec` file that is generate on each run. To have `make` smartly build an `rpm spec` file?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do this, but you are way too vague here and I'm guessing that is why there are few answers. A suggestion is to write the _smallest_ makefiles and `rpm spec` that demonstrates the gist of what you are doing. With that, someone like me might be able to add the few additional lines to the Makefile.